# loading menu with binary serialization

Tags: java, swing, serialization, load

I'm doing a naval battle game in java,i created a menu with JMenubar and I want to be able to save and load a game.

I created a class **chargerActionListener** which implements ActionListener
to add it to an item in my menu but it does not work, this does not return an error to me, but does not load the **plateau** object, my loading function is correct i tested it.

```
 package actionlistener;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

import Main.Plateau;
import interfaceGraphique.Fenetre;
import ioforme.IOPlateau;

public class ChargerActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public Fenetre fenetre;
    public Plateau plateau;
    public ChargerActionListener(Fenetre fenetre)
    {
        this.fenetre = fenetre;


    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        JFileChooser choix = new JFileChooser();
        int retour=choix.showOpenDialog(fenetre);
        if(retour==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

            try {


                Plateau p = IOPlateau.lire(choix.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                fenetre.setPlateau(p);
                System.out.println(choix.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

                fenetre.actualiserGrilleCible();
                fenetre.actualiserMaGrille();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

I wrote this code quickly, it works perfectly but the same problem.
I have three buttons; one to save, to load and to display the human object in the console, I can save without worry.
**for example** : I launch the program with **human ("jean", 10)** (in the main function)
I save.
I quit my program and I change
**human ("jean", 50)** 
when I press the load button
I load my file previously save
and I click on the button to display in the console it will display me
"Human [jean, 50]"
but I want "Human [jean, 10]"

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.*;



public class Main  {

    public static class Human implements Serializable {
        String name;
        int age;
        public Human(String name, int age) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return "Human [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
        }


    }


    public static class ChargerActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public Fenetre fenetre;

        public ChargerActionListener(Fenetre fenetre)
        {
            this.fenetre = fenetre;


        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser choix = new JFileChooser();
            int retour=choix.showOpenDialog(null);
            if(retour==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                try {


                    Human h  = IOPlateau.lire(choix.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                    fenetre.setHuman(h);
                    System.out.println(choix.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }

    }
    public static class SauvegarderActionListener implements ActionListener {
        public Fenetre fenetre;

        public SauvegarderActionListener(Fenetre fenetre)
        {
            this.fenetre = fenetre;


        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser choix = new JFileChooser();
            int retour=choix.showSaveDialog(null);
            if(retour==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){

                try {


                    IOPlateau.sauver(fenetre.getHuman(),choix.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

                    System.out.println(choix.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }

    }
    public static class Fenetre extends JFrame {

        private Human human;

        Fenetre (Human human)
        {
            this.human = human;
            this.setTitle("test");
            this.setSize(1200,500);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
            JButton save = new JButton ();
            save.addActionListener(new SauvegarderActionListener(this));
            JButton load = new JButton();
            load.addActionListener(new ChargerActionListener(this));
            JButton display = new JButton ();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel (new GridLayout(1,3));
            // Button for load and save !
            panel.add(save);
            panel.add(load);
            panel.add(display);

            this.setContentPane(panel);
            display.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evenement) 
                {
                    System.out.println(human);
                }
            });
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        public void setHuman (Human human)
        {
            this.human = human;
        }
        public Human getHuman ()
        {
            return this.human;
        }


    }

    public static class IOPlateau {

        public static Human lire(String fileName) throws IOException {

                Human h = null;
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
                try {
                        h = (Human) ois.readObject();
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                    // erreur de lecture
                } catch (EOFException eofe) {
                    //fin de fichier
                }
                ois.close();
                return h;
        }

        public static void sauver(Human h, String fileName) throws IOException {
            try {

                // Recevoir le fichier 
                File f = new File(fileName);

                // Créer un nouveau fichier
                // Vérifier s'il n'existe pas
                if (f.createNewFile())
                    System.out.println("File created");
                else
                    System.out.println("File already exists");
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
            ObjectOutputStream oos;
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            oos.writeObject(h);
            oos.close();

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Human human = new Human ("Jean",11);
        Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre(human);


    }

}
```

Comment: You've got a bug in your code *somewhere*. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting in your question as an [edit] a valid [mre]. Please read the link as it will explain how to create one of these as well as how it can help you get answers, and help us by improving the quality of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the `actionListener()` method associated with the *display* `JButton` . Because the class member `human` has the same name as the parameter in the constructor for class `Fenetre`, everywhere in the constructor code where you want to access the member (and not the parameter) you need to qualify it using the `this` keyword.

Here is how method `actionListener()` should be written:

```java
display.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evenement) {
        System.out.println(Fenetre.this.human);
    }
});
```

You need `Fenetre.this.human` because you are creating an anonymous, inner class and `human` is a member of the enclosing class.

If you are using at least Java 8, you can replace the anonymous, inner class with a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) since interface `java.awt.event.ActionListener` is a functional interface, i.e. an interface that contains exactly one abstract method. Here is the lambda expression to replace the anonymous, inner class.

```java
display.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println(this.human));
```

As you can see, in the lambda expression you only need to write `this.human` in order to access the member `human` of class `Fenetre`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your ChargerActionListener to the item correctly:

```
.addActionListener(new ChargerActionListener(fenetre));
```

Also try using:

```
JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
```

Maybe 'null' as an argument for 'showOpenDialog' will work.
(I don't know what fenetre or plateau should be)

Also maybe only the dialog won't open, but the Listener is actually being called.

Please check that by running something like (in 'actionPerformed'):

```
System.out.println("Ok");
```

Comment: yes i already did that when i click on the event is well activated, i do make a minamal example to show my problem

Comment: @MonsieurAZERTY: this is exactly the reason why I made my request that you create and post a decent [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that folks don't need to make wild guesses as to what is causing your problem (as shown here).

Answer (score 0):

Your serialization code works fine. Your problem is in how you display the result obtained. You do this:

```
public static class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    private Human human;

    Fenetre(Human human) {
        this.human = human;

        // ....

        display.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evenement) {
                System.out.println(human);
            }
        });

        // ....
    }

    // ....
}
```

Your `System.out.println(human);` call is referring to the parameter passed into the constructor, not the field of the class, and so the value never changes.

If you now change your code to:

```
public static class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    private Human human;

    Fenetre(Human human) {
        this.human = human;

        // ....

        display.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evenement) {
                System.out.println(getHuman());
            }
        });

        // ....
    }

    // ....
}
```

Since `getHuman()` returns the value held by the instance field, human, you will see that the result is correct, that the human field reference value has in fact changed.

Comment: yes thank you, I discovered this problem, but now I have a  problem of conception.
because my window change its attribute well but all the elements of the "Fenetre" (my window) are pointing to the old element "Plateau"(object) of the window. I therefore find a solution which consists in closing the "window" and recreating another. but I do not find this solution very clean I have a little trouble to conceptualize my graphical interfaces